# php class import excel to mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I use this library to import excel data to mysql database

[excel to mysql](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187)

and this library work fine on localhost and all is ok

but when i upload my files to my host on godaddy i recieve this error when i try to test the code online

> **Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/mhmd2991/public_html/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 94**

this is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnImport'])){
    if(!empty($_FILES['ecxelfile']['tmp_name'])){
        $fileName=explode(".",$_FILES['ecxelfile']['name']);
        if($fileName[1]=="xls" || $fileName[1]=="xlsx"){
         $file=$_FILES['ecxelfile']['tmp_name'];
include("../PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
$objPHPExcel=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
foreach($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet){
    $highestRow=$worksheet->getHighestRow();
    for($row=2;$row<=$highestRow;$row++){
$A =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue());
$category =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$row)->getValue());
$AA=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getValue());
$AAA=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$row)->getValue());
$taskname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$row)->getValue());
$predecessors=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$row)->getValue());
$unit=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$row)->getValue());
$qty=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7,$row)->getValue());
$wo=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8,$row)->getValue());
$duration=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9,$row)->getValue());
$startdate=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10,$row)->getValue());
$enddate=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11,$row)->getValue());
$asd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12,$row)->getValue());
$add=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(13,$row)->getValue());
$aduration=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(14,$row)->getValue());
$transferredto=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(15,$row)->getValue());
$prb=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(16,$row)->getValue());
$anotes=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(17,$row)->getValue());
$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(18,$row)->getValue());
$projectname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(19,$row)->getValue()); 
$subcategory=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(20,$row)->getValue());  
$client=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(21,$row)->getValue());
 $query=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into tbl_activities (db_A,db_category,db_AA,db_AAA,db_taskname,db_predecessors,db_unit,db_qty,db_wo,db_duration,db_startdate,db_enddate,db_asd,db_add,db_aduration,db_transferredto,db_prb,db_anotes,db_user,db_projectname,db_subcategory,db_client) values('$A', '$category','$AA','$AAA','$taskname','$predecessors','$unit','$qty','$wo','$duration','$startdate','$enddate','$asd','$add','$aduration','$transferredto','$prb','$anotes','$user','$projectname','$subcategory','$client')")or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
    }
}
header("location:activitiesimport.php?msg=1");
        }else{echo"You Should upload an excel file.";}
    }else{echo"Please choose a file";}
}
```

**Any one have an experience with this library can help me to solve this problem online??**

Comment: Is PHP's zip extension available on godaddy?

Comment: @MarkBaker i don't know

Comment: There is a painless way to import excel data to mysql : save as CSV in xl and then do LOAD DATA INFILE in mysql

Comment: @e4c5 i know this method and i already do it before but know i want only from an excel without save as csv file

Comment: a waste of not just your time but everyone elses as well

Comment: @e4c5 but this library work and this mean we can do it and it's work on my localhost but my problem is online i don't thing this a waste of time

Comment: you need to install the ZipArchive class in your hosting environment. Make sure all the pre-requisites for PHPExcel - listed here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/01-Getting-Started.md are met by the environment. You may have to ask the host to install missing components. If they won't for any reason, then you're a bit stuck. Probably would have been worth verifying this before building the solution!